# Empty objects returned in response entity

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

- List item

I'm trying to return a list of json objects in my spring boot application.
This is the controller,

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/movies")
public class MovieController {
    @Autowired
    private Movieservice movieService;
    @RequestMapping("/getMovies")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Movie>> allMovies() {
        return new ResponseEntity<List<Movie>>(movieService.allMovies(),HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

This is the service class,

```
@Service
public class Movieservice {
    
    @Autowired
    private Movierepository movieRepository;
    
    public List<Movie> allMovies() {
        return movieRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

This is the repository interface

```
@Repository
public interface Movierepository extends MongoRepository<Movie,ObjectId>{
    
}
```

This is my Movie class

```
@Document(collection ="Movies")
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Movie {
    @Id
    private ObjectId id;
    private String imdbId;
    private String title;
    private String releaseDate;
    private String trailerLink;
    private List<String> genres;
    private String poster;
    private List<String> backdrops;
    @DocumentReference
    private List<Review> reviewIds;

}
```

This is my Review class

```
@Document(collection = "reviews")
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor 
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Review {
    @Id
    private ObjectId id;
    private String body;
 
}
```

This is my output

```
[
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{},
{}
]
```

1. Checked if movie entity class matches mongodb
2. Ensured connection to mongodb is right

Comment: Can you also post contents of `Movie` class

Comment: done, I've edited my question to include it